# Using multiple themes in UWP apps

Tags: styles, windows-10, win-universal-app, multilingual

I have a multi-language app with two styles named `RtlStyles` and `LtrStyles` for RTL and LTR Languages.
I've defined my style in App.xaml Like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/RtlStyles.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

But my problem is how can I change style to `LtrStyles` in code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Gaurav I have a little update on his  answer. First I wrote a method for choosing themes:

```
public static void ChooseTheme()
{
        ResourceDictionary rd;
        if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name == "en-US")
            rd = new ResourceDictionary
            {
                Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Styles/LtrStyles.xaml", UriKind.Absolute)
            };
        else
            rd = new ResourceDictionary
            {
                Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Styles/RtlStyles.xaml", UriKind.Absolute)
            };

        Application.Current.Resources = rd;
}
```

And then we can use it everywhere (e.g `Page_Tapped` event of layout).

Answer (score 2):

In App.OnLaunched(), you can try something like this:

```
    if (someCondition)
    {
        var rd = new ResourceDictionary
        {
            Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Styles/RtlStyles.xaml", UriKind.Absolute)
        };
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ,The solution has no error but not worked too!